# Solr Query for a a Unique pair

Tags: apache, solr, solr4, solrcloud, solr5

I have Solr documents having 3 fields Sender, Receiver and Time. I want to query what is the total time for all unique pair of Sender+Reciever.

Below is Solr Document format and 4 record(for example):

**Sender Reciever Time**

1. John     Robert   10
2. John     Rocky    20
3. Robert   John     10
4. Rocky    John     20

Expected Output

1. John   Robert ->Total Time = 20*(10+10)*
2. John   Rocky ->Total Time = 40*(20+20)*

What is the query that I can write for it(single or nested). I tried *stats* but I am not able to put condition for a unique pair.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [the signature generated from those two fields](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/De-Duplication) and then group/stat on those. But you need to do that during indexing time.

Comment: Can u tell me the exact query ?

Comment: This is not during query. This is during indexing. Then you would do statistics/grouping/whatever during query on that signature field.